# Are the RMI requests handled per process or thread on server side?

Tags: java, rmi

Are the RMI requests handled per process or per thread on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it isn't specified. The RMI specification says something like 'there is no guaranteed association between client threads and server threads'.

About all that you can deduce from that is that *you cannot assume RMI is single-threaded.* In practice you will have found that your RMI remote object can be called by multiple server-side threads at the same time. So synchronization is up to you.

This is the best sense I can make out of your question: I must say I don't know what the difference between 'per-process' and 'per-thread' actually means.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question.  per-process or per-thread means when a client issues a remote call, is a process or thread be invoked to handle this remote call.

Comment: @Terminal User that question doesn't really make sense when you consider RMI. *Your remote object* is invoked in the JVM it was exported from. That process. And which thread in that process isn't specified.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://gsraj.tripod.com/java/rmi_internals.html):

> 8: On the server side, when a client connects to the server socket, a new thread is forked to deal with the incoming call. The original thread can continue listening to the original socket so that additional calls from other clients can be made.

Comment: There are numerous errors and omissions  in 'this', which rules it out as an authoritative reference. In any case it is not an official Sun/Oracle specification.